# XMLWriter VS. XML helper from CodeIgniter. Which one is faster and better Performance?

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, xmlwriter

XMLWriter VS. XML helper from CodeIgniter. Which one is faster and better Performance ?
Still not see result from anywhere.

ps.already search in stackoverflow and google.
ps2.may be , I'm bad searcher. ;w;

Comment: Have you tried performance testing them at all?

Comment: Nope. I have no skill in CI. So I just want to know to make decision what I should use. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMLWriter and the CodeIgniter XML helper solve very different problems, so I'm not sure a fair comparison can be made between the two. XMLWriter is used to programmatically build XML in a structured and robust manner. The CodeIgniter XML helper provides a single function that just takes a string as input and converts specific reserved XML characters to entities.

If you're building extremely simple XML, you might be OK just using the CodeIgniter XML helper. If there's any complexity in building your XML or you want an OO interface for building the XML, you'll want to use XMLWriter.

Comment: I think my xml is simple but i use XMLWriter for now. I do more code but can appect it. :)

Comment: There is also SimpleXMLElement in PHP which can be used to create simple XML documents with quite some options.